# Retrieving ID's of imported CSV (LOAD DATA INFILE)

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I have the following scenario:

I have to import a CSV file to a table. For this i use the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

Is there a way to retrieve the id's (column 'id') of all inserted rows, since i need them in next step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an BEFORE INSERT or AFTER INSERT trigger and store inserted ID values into another table -

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table2(id) VALUES (NEW.id);
END
```

Comment: I think if more users upload data at the same time?